# Manipulating arrays and appending strings in complicated ways

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, loops

I am some what a beginner in jquery/javascript. I am familiar with how it works, but its been a minute since I have worked with it and recently i've been tasked with something that I think jquery/html would be best for.

So I have a list of 500 refund numbers, i put them into a text box, click a button, and they currently go into an array, I know this works as when I alert the array, I see my values.

What I need some guidance with is how can I take the numbers in this array and make it populate a textbox that looks like the below.

```
send "REFUNDNUMBER1<f1>"   #This is our refund number
send "5<f1>"      # This LINE will come after every single refund number
```

So as you can see, i need to append : send "  to the front of the refund number, and "  to the end of it and then add send "5"  to the line beneath it.

Essentially I am trying to generate a script for someone and if this is the wrong place for help I apologize sincerely, I just need some solid direction so that I can understand what I need to do and how to do it. I have very minimal experience with for loops and arrays unfortunately. and javascript for that matter.

Below is my html code/jquery

```
<div class="home-content">
<div class="home-heading">
<h1><em>Accounting</em> Void Refund Script Generator</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<form>
Refund Numbers<br>
<textarea cols="38" rows="27" name="refundNumbers" id="refundNumberstxt"> </textarea>
</form> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input type="text" name="companyNumb" size="2">
<button type="button" class="btn" id="generateButton">Generate Scripts</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#generateButton").click( function(){
    var txtRefundNumbers = $("#refundNumberstxt").val();
    var arrayRefundNumbers = txtRefundNumbers.split('\n');
    var msg = ""

    var arrayVoidRefundsOutput = arrayRefundNumbers.map(function(x) { 
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayRefundNumbers.length; i++) {
            return 'send "' + arrayRefundNumbers [i] + '"\nsend "5"\n'; 
            }
    }).join('');
    alert(arrayVoidRefundsOutput)

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayVoidRefundsOutput.length; i++) {
    msg += arrayVoidRefundsOutput  + "\n";
    }
});
});
```

The html and jquery are in their own files fyi.

with the help of irkeninvader i was able to get this. I now get this

send "1"
send "5"
send "1"
send "5"
send "1"
send "5"
send "1"
send "5

which is not what im looking for and I am confused,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` lets you modify each value in an array.  You should be able to use this to add text to the beginning and end of each refund number.

After using `map` to add the appropriate text, use `join` to create one long string again as your output.

```
var output = textread.map(function(refundNum) { 
  return 'send "' + refundNum + '"\nsend "5"\n'; 
}).join('');
```

I assume I didn't get that quite right but you should be able to modify it to get the correct text before and after each refund number.

The `output` variable should now contain your result.  Do whatever you need to with it (put its contents into another texteara, log/alert it, etc).

That would make your click handler look like this:

```
$("#generateButton").click( function(){
    var txt = $("#refundNumberstxt").val();
    var textread = txt.split('\n');

    var output = textread.map(function(refundNum) { 
      return 'send "' + refundNum + '"\nsend "5"\n'; 
    }).join('');

    alert(output);
});
```

Comment: How does function(refundNum) know what my array values are? would I need to change that to the my array variable?

Comment: `map` is a function that all arrays have, `function(refundNum)` will be called once for each element in the array, and whatever is returned from `function(refundNum)` will replace the old value essentially.

Comment: to see what's going on maybe try a simpler example, paste this into your console `['a', 'b', 'c'].map(function(val){ return 'mapped ' + val; })`

Comment: also - the name of the variable inside of the map function doesn't matter.  `val` / `refundNum` are just names I gave it to make it more readable.  Some people use `x` all the time, just preference.

Comment: Okay I understand it now, the problem I am having now though, is when I alert the new array, I get "send "1,2,3,4" send "5" send "1,2,3,4" etc... Could you help me understand why that is happening? i tried putting the .map function into the for loops, but then instead of getting one alert with my new array, i get a pop up alert for each value in the array.

Comment: does your handler look like what I added?

Comment: When I made my handler look like yours, I got an "undefined" in place of the refund number spot. I edited what my jquery looks like at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: I don't think you want to have a loop inside of the map function...if you could create a jsfiddle showing your problem I might be able to fix it up for you

Comment: So what I notice is, if I use alert(arrayVoidRefundsOutput [3]) I still get the 1 as my value, Maybe im not understanding arrays the right way but it looks to me like its changing each value in the array to send "1" Ill work on that jsfiddle right now

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/htrww76j/1/ @Irkeninvader I am not sure if alert works on jsfiddle.

Comment: You just had to tell it you are using jquery (frameworks & extensions under the javascript button at the top right of the js pane) is this close to what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/htrww76j/3/

Comment: Yes exactly!! It hardly looks like you changed the code except for the x. What changed? Thanks a ton for the help.

Comment: yeah you were really close - the function inside `map` is called once for every string in your array, so x = 123 the first time it executes, x = 456 the second time, etc.  So we can add text to the beginning and end of each string in the array by returning 'start str ' + `x` + ' end str'

Comment: the loop afterward isn't needed because the `.join('')` already created one long string out of the modified array values

Comment: You are the man! Thanks for being patient with me. I learned quite a bit.

Comment: That's great! Good luck on the rest of your app

Comment: Quick question, After the map function, does that variable stay as an array? or is it simply a string now. I am pretty sure you answered that question two comments above by explaining what the .join("") does but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: `arrayRefundNumbers` will still be an array, map doesn't change the array you call it on.  `arrayVoidRefundsOutput` is just a string though.  If you want to have an array of modified values you could do the join later and save it as a different variable like this: https://jsfiddle.net/htrww76j/4/

Comment: check the console after generate scripts and the alerts (f12 in chrome) to see the new array values